# How does C++ store functions and objects in memory?

Tags: c++, function, turbo-c

Lets say we have a class

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    void sayHi()
    {
        cout<<"Hi";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a=NULL;
    a->sayHi();
}
```

The above code will compile on Turbo C (where I tested) and print `Hi` as output.

I was expecting crash because `a` is `NULL`. More over if I make `sayHi()` function virtual, it says

```
Abnormal temination(Segmentation fault in gcc)
```

I know a lot of it is implementation dependent but if anybody could throw some light on any implementation or just give an overview it would be really nice.

Comment: Calling a method through a null pointer is undefined behaviour. Anything may happen - it doesn't have to crash, but the standard allows it.

Comment: Not a C++ guy, so this is a guess, but: your code doesn't need to access any of the memory of an instance of `A`. `sayHi()` doesn't use the field `x`, and it's not virtual so it doesn't need to access the vtable to resolve. A C++ compiler would actually have to insert a check to see whether `a` is a valid pointer to cause an error.

Comment: btw - turbo c is an ancient relic. there are many other free dev environments you can use

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, the code has undefined behavior, i.e., whatever you get is by chance. That said, the system doesn't need to know about the object when calling a non-virtual member function: It can just be called based on the signature. Further, if a member function doesn't need to access a member, it doesn't need really need an object at all and can just run. This is what you observed when the code printed some output. Whether this is how the system is implemented isn't defined, however, i.e., nothing says it works.

When calling a virtual function type system starts off looking at a type information record associated with the object. When calling a virtual function on a `NULL` pointer, no such information exists and attempting to access it probably leads to some sort of crash. Still, it doesn't have to but it does for most system.

BTW, `main()` **always** returns `int`.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, the methods of a class are not stored inside the instances of that class. They're simply some "special" functions that transparently accept the `this` pointer in addition to the arguments specified by the programmer.

In your case, the `sayHi()` method does not reference any of the class fields, therefore, the `this` pointer (which is `NULL`) is never followed.

Make no mistake, though, this is still undefined behavior. Your program may choose to send nasty emails to your contact list when you invoke this. In this particular instance, it does the worst thing, and appears to work.

The `virtual` method case has been added since I answered the question, but I won't refine my answer, since it's included by others' answers.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that undefined behaviour that "works" is BAD.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the layout of a object instantiated from a class is as follows:

```
* - v_ptr  ---> *  pTypeInfo
|               |- pVirtualFuncA
|               |- pVirtualFuncB
|- MemberVariableA
|- MemberVariableB
```

`v_ptr` is a pointer to the v-table - which contains addresses of virtual functions and RTTI data for the object.  Classes without virtual functions don't have v-tables and the corresponding objects don't have `v_ptr`.

In your example above, `class A` has no virtual methods and thus no v-table. This means the implementation of `sayHi()` to call can be determined at compile time and is invariant.

The compiler generates code that sets the implicit `this` pointer to `a` and then jumps to the beginning of `sayHi()`.  Since the implementation has no need for the object's contents, the fact that it works when the pointer is `NULL` is a happy coincidence.

If you were to make `sayHi()` virtual, the compiler cannot determine the implementation to call at compiler time, so instead generates code that looks up the address of the function in the v-table and calls it.   In your example where `a` is `NULL`, the compiler reads the contents of address `0`, causing the abort.

Comment: The fact that the class A has no virtual methods is not relevant. What is important is that the particular function being called, sayHi, is not a virtual function and does not use members of the class object. So this function can be (and is) called without using the pointer to the class object.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a non-virtual method of a class, for the compiler it is enough to know what class the function belongs to and by dereferencing - albeit a NULL - pointer to a class to call the method, the compiler gets that information. The **sayHi()** method is pretty much just a function that takes pointer to the class instance as a hidden parameter. This pointer is NULL but that doesn't matter if you do not reference any attributes in the method.

The moment you make this method virtual, the situation changes. The compiler does not know what code is associated with the method at compile time any more and must figure that out at the runtime. What it does is that it looks into a table that basically contains function pointers for all virtual methods; this table is associated with the class instance so it looks at piece of the memory relative to the NULL pointer and therefore crashes in this case.