# Where are member functions stored for an object?

Tags: c++, memory, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm experimenting with C++ to understand how class/structures and their respective objects are laid out in memory and I understood that each field of a class/structure is an offset into their respective object (so I can have a member variable pointer).

I don't understand why, even if I can have member function pointers, the following code doesn't work:

```
struct mystruct
{
    void function()
    {
        cout << "hello world";
    }
    int c;
};

int main() 
{ 
    unsigned int offset_from_start_structure = (unsigned int)(&((mystruct*)0)->c);
    unsigned int offset_from_start_structure2 = (unsigned int)(&((mystruct*)0)->function); // ERROR - error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression



    return 0;
}
```

My question is: why does the line

```
unsigned int offset_from_start_structure = (unsigned int)(&((mystruct*)0)->c);
```

compile and returns me the offset of the "c" field from the start of the structure and the line

```
unsigned int offset_from_start_structure2 = (unsigned int)(&((mystruct*)0)->function);
```

doesn't even compile?

Comment: Member functions are not stored in objects (why would they? They are the same for all objects of that type). And if it helps (maybe not; maybe it only adds confusion but I'll try anyway) member function pointers are *not* pointers.

Comment: What were you expecting the contents of the _function_ to be, in memory? Functions are not data. They are code.

Comment: "I'm experimenting with C++ to understand how class/structures and their respective objects are laid out in memory" implementation details, has nothing to with the language

Comment: @Johnny Pauling Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660829/how-does-c-store-functions-and-objects-in-memory) as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Member functions or pointers to them aren't stored in the object. (`virtual` functions are typically called through a pointer stored in a table to which an object has a single pointer to) This would be a **huge** waste of memory. They're typically stored in a code memory section, and are known to the compiler. The object (`*this`) is typically passed as an *invisible* parameter so the functions know on which object to operate when they are called.

So, in layman terms, you'd have

```
 0x10001000    void A::foo
 ..........    {code for A::foo}
```

and

```
 push a;
 call A::foo (0x10001000)
 pop a;
```

where `a` is the object you're calling `foo` on.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification but why doesn't the line work? It should return a fixed address at least

Comment: @JohnnyPauling no, it shouldn't. The `&((mystruct*)0)->c` is undefined behavior, you can't just dereference a null pointer. Google for `pointer to member function` and you'll find the proper way of doing it.

Comment: I don't think it's an undefined behavior, it returns the offset of the c field every time I call it and it works for other consecutive fields too so I was wondering why it won't work with a function

Comment: @JohnnyPauling regardless of whether you think so or not, it is undefined behavior. The `->` attempts to dereference an invalid pointer.

Comment: I believe you, but why won't the other line compile? It should be the same undefined behaviour as well

Comment: @JohnnyPauling the compiler checks for valid syntax (not so much for UB). The second line is simply invalid syntax. That's not how you "get" a pointer to a member function, and I already told you how you can find out how to do it.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: The `p->memberFunc` expression is a funny beast, e.g. it has no type. All you can do with it is call it. If C++ had been a designed instead of an evolved language, then this would have been something like a C# delegate, but no, it just isn't something you can pass around.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: What is the *huge* memory waste to referred to? Is it not just sizeof(ptr) * num_of_virtual_functions_in_the_scope? Did you mean that overhead itself  as huge or is there any other memory wastage as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Member function pointers are in practice not stored in objects: there's no need. The C++ standard doesn't specify exactly how e.g. virtual functions are to be implemented, but the common practice for virtual member functions is that each object contains a pointer to a table of function pointers; this pointer is called a **[vtable pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)**.

You might try to get hold of **[“Inside the C++ object model”](http://books.google.no/books/about/Inside_the_C++_Object_Model.html?id=hLdmQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)** by Stanley Lippman.

Or, you might just try to get hold of my old **[pointers tutorial](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4)**, which was once referenced from Wikipedia's pointers article, before my then homepage site disappeared.

---

Regarding the second question, why taking the address of `p->memberFunc` makes the compiler choke a little, well that expression has no type, it's just a *syntactical entity*, which you can apply an argument list to in order to call the function.

To wit,

```
struct S
{
    void foo() {}
};

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    S* p = 0;
    typeid( &p->foo );
}
```

Compilation:

```
[W:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:12:17: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&S::foo' [-fpermissive]
foo.cpp:12:22: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
foo.cpp:12:22: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

[W:\dev\test]
> _
```